# Calculating days, hours, minutes, seconds, until 2038

Tags: java, computer-science

I need to get the days,hours, minutes, seconds from current time till 2038.I am having issues with the output.

```
public class Assignment1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
long y2k38 = (long) Math.pow(2, 31)*1000;
long diffmillis = y2k38-now;
long diffsec = (y2k38-now)/1000;
long diffmin = diffsec/60;
long diffhours = diffmin/60;
long diffdays = diffhours/24;

System.out.printf(
    "Y2K38 will occur in %d days.\n"+
    "Y2K38 will occur in %d hours.\n"+
    "Y2K38 will occur in %d minutes.\n"+
    "Y2K38 will occur in %d seconds.\n",
    (diffdays%24),(diffhours%60), (diffmin%60),(diffsec%60));
}

}
```

Comment: This isn't a code completion site. What code have you written so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Welcome to [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) please share what you have tried. then if you got stucked with some exact issue, we will help you. Refer these links for asking proper questions (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , (http://stackoverflow.com//help/mcve) and (http://sscce.org)

Comment: @connorp just posted it

Comment: @Michael I didn't realize that sorry. I just posted the code I was having issues with. I am not getting an accurate number when I run it.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that your `diffdays`, `diffhours`, `diffmin`, and `diffsec` are all just constants that don't actually interact with the current timestamp, so `y2k38-diffdays`, `y2k38-diffhours`, and `y2k38-diffmin` are simply constants subtracting constants.

You will likely want to calculate the number of milliseconds until 2038 with `y2k38-now`, and then convert up to the units you want from there.

For example, `(y2k38-now)/1000` should give you seconds until 2038, `(y2k38-now)/(60*1000)` should give you minutes, etc.

Comment: thanks for the help! Should i just get rid of diffdays, hours, etc all together?

Comment: You could, if you don't have any use for them.  Alternatively, you can store the proper difference values there and display them.  Either way, it shouldn't make much of an actual difference in the functionality of the code.

Comment: `public class Assignment1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long y2k38 = (long) Math.pow(2, 31);
    System.out.printf(
        "Y2K38 will occur in %f days.\n"+
        "Y2K38 will occur in %f hours.\n"+
        "Y2K38 will occur in %f minutes.\n"+
        "Y2K38 will occur in %f seconds.\n",
      (y2k38-now)/(1000*60*60*24), (y2k38-now)/(1000*60*60), (y2k38-now)/(1000*60) ,(y2k38-now)/(1000);  
  }
} `

Comment: that is my updated code, but I am still having issues compiling it. I get a error: Assignment1.java:12: error: ';' expected

Comment: It's hard to tell from the lack of formatting, but did you close the parentheses on your printf statement?

Comment: @ AllenTsang I can't post long lines of code in the comments, but I updated the original question up top with my current code if you could take a look. Thanks again for the help. much appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, it definitely looks like your printf statement is missing a closing parenthesis, just before the `;`.  Fix that and try again.

Comment: I get this as an output after closing the paren: `Y2K38 will occur in Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.Long
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:2806)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2753)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520)
 at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
 at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
 at Assignment1.main(Assignment1.java:5)`

Comment: Use %d in your printf statement instead of %f, longs are not floats.

Comment: tried that but the output came back negative. Is it possible the conversions are not accurate?

Comment: Just checked, the conversions are fine, but your 2038 timestamp unit doesn't match the current timestamp unit.  That is, your 2038 timestamp is in seconds, and your current time is in milliseconds, so there's a difference of a factor of 1000, and your number gets thrown off when you subtract the two.  One way of fixing this is by having `long y2k38 = (long) Math.pow(2, 31)*1000;` instead.

Comment: Wow guess I just over looked that. Finally got it, thank you so much for your help! The out put came out as: `Y2K38 will occur in 8161 days.
Y2K38 will occur in 195884 hours.
Y2K38 will occur in 11753091 minutes.
Y2K38 will occur in 705185505 seconds.` How can I make it output as: `8161 days
20 hours
59 minutes
12 seconds`

Comment: If you use the modulo operator (%), you can get the remainder from a division operation, which will be helpful here.  For example, if you have 123 hours, 123/24 will give you the number of days (5), while 123%24 will give you the remaining number of hours (3).  As a side note, this is where it may have been useful to have stored the number of each unit individually, to reduce the number of calculations.

Comment: I will probably in that case reassign each unit a variable inorder to get that output. Where do I place the (%)?

Comment: Let's assume you have the total number of seconds difference stored in a variable `diffsec`.  From there, you could get `diffmin` from `diffsec/60`, and the remaining number of seconds to display from `diffsec%60`.  You can work your way up the units this way, storing each larger unit as you go.

Comment: So what value would I assign to diffsec?

Comment: Assuming you changed your Y2K38 timestamp to be in milliseconds, you could get a `diffmillis` out of `y2k38-now` and work up from there, despite the fact that you don't need to display the milliseconds in your solution.

Comment: so `long diffsec = y2k38-now%1000` then I could get `diffmin` from that by doing `diffsec%60` then hours by `diffsec%60%60`.

Comment: First problem: going up to larger units, you just want to `/`, not `%`.  So, `diffmin = diffsec/60`, etc.  Think like: if you have 60 seconds, that means you have 1 minute.  As you can see, minutes = seconds/60.

The `%` is for: say you have 63 seconds, and you want it to display 1 minute 3 seconds.  You get get the "1 minute" from `63/60`, and the "3 seconds" from `63%60`.

Second problem: Order of operations on your `diffsec` calculation - you need to make sure the subtraction happens first.  Along with the first problem, this means you get `long diffsec = (y2k38-now)/1000`

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me. As for the `%` where exactly in the code does it fit in then? I understand `diffsec%60` will provide me with the remaining second output, but how do I also get the days, hours, min, to that format?

Comment: Similar to `diffsec%60` giving you the remaining seconds, `diffmin%60` will give you the remaining minutes, and `diffhours%24` will give you the remaining hours.

Comment: Also, `long diffhours = diffmin/60*60` should instead just be `long diffhours = diffmin/60`.  If you already have `diffmin` storing the appropriate number of minutes, you only need to do one step of unit conversion at a time: in this case just the `/60`.

Comment: Also, currently, your code is showing the number of hours, minutes, seconds, **and milliseconds**, and you haven't actually made the calculation to find the number of days, which would be `diffhours/24`.

Comment: Okay I changed the `diffhours= diffmin/60;` . The out put is still off: `Y2K38 will occur in 22 days.
Y2K38 will occur in 42 hours.
Y2K38 will occur in 23 minutes.
Y2K38 will occur in 700 seconds.`  it should be `8160 days
22 hours
38 minutes
47 seconds`

Comment: Did you read the other comment I made after that?  It sounds like you're still displaying hours, minutes, seconds, and **milliseconds**, all mislabeled one unit over.

Comment: Yeah I just read your other comment and made the change to `diffday=diffhours/24` .I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing incorrectly with the units. Also are my `%` in the correct places? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: You are still calling `%d`s on `(diffhours%24),(diffmin%60*60), (diffsec%60),(diffmillis%1000)`, in that order.  `(diffhours%24)` gives you the remaining number of hours, not days.  `(diffmin%60*60)` should be `(diffmin%60)`, and gives the remaining number of minutes, not hours.  `(diffsec%60)` gives you the remaining number of seconds.  `(diffmillis%1000)` gives you the remaining number of milliseconds, which you are not actually looking for.  And you get the number of remaining days from `diffhours/24`.  Also, if all the code is updated, you still haven't changed the value of `diffhours`.

Comment: What should I change the `%d` to? I updated the current with everything you mentioned in the comment. I am getting accurate output from hours, minutes, seconds. I updated the code above with the current one.

Comment: The `%d` is fine, I was just saying how they were referring to the wrong numbers.  Now, instead of `diffdays%24`, you just want `diffdays`, since you don't need to change the units beyond that.

Comment: I got it! Thank you again for your help!